# addTo failing to add

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have 2 domain classes: Category and CatAttribute, they have a many-to-one relationship, Category has 2 List of CatAttribute.

```
class Category {

    static constraints = {
        description nullable: true
        name unique: true
    }


    static hasMany = [params:CatAttribute, specs:CatAttribute]
    static mappedBy = [params: "none", specs: "none"]
    static mapping = {
    }

    List<CatAttribute> params  //required attributes
    List<CatAttribute> specs   //optional attributes
    String name
    String description        


}
```

and my CatAttribute class:

```
class CatAttribute {

    static constraints = {
    }
    static belongsTo = [category: Category]
    String name

}
```

When I tried to create new objects, it fails to save:

```
def someCategory = new Category(name: "A CATEGORY")
.addToSpecs(new CatAttribute(name: "SOMETHING"))
.addToParams(new CatAttribute(name: "onemore attribute"))
.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

The domain classes here are simplified/data are mocked for illustration purposes only, the real production code is a lot more complex, but the relationship between the two domains is the same.

Validation errors occur on .addToSpec line:

```
Field error in object 'Category' on field 'specs[0].category': rejected value [null];
```

This error has to do with me putting 2 lists of `CatAttribute` objects in the same domain `Category`, if I remove either of those and proceed with my object creation,everything is perfectly fine, the way I mapped the domain class `Category` is all based on [grails ref](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html) 
, so i don't think there is anything wrong with the mapping, but if there is, please let me know.

Comment: What you have shown above is an example of 2 `one-many` relationships instead of `many-one`.

Comment: @dmahapatro Any way to make this work?

Comment: Do you need the back reference on CatAttribute?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the associations as `List` (do you index), by default they are `Set`.
Modify Category as below and you should be good:

```
class Category {
    String name
    String description

    static hasMany = [params: CatAttribute, specs: CatAttribute]
    static mappedBy = [params: "category", specs: "category"]

    static constraints = {
        description nullable: true
        name unique: true
        params nullable: true //optional
    }
}
```

if you need a 1:m relation.

Comment: if I change my mappedBy, it wouldn't be compile-able, new error: 
Caused by MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: CatAttribute column: category_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: @16dots Did you remove `List<CatAttribute> params` and `List<CatAttribute> specs`? Which version of Grails?

Comment: unfortunately I need both of them as Lists, because the objects has to be in order.  So I am guessing there is no way out of this?